# Query an object array to check if it contains an array of strings in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

say i have the following inside my db:

```
knights
  {
    name: 'Knightley',
    skills: [
      { name: 'sword', level: 2 },
      { name: 'shield', level: 1 }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Cowardly',
    skills: [
      { name: 'sword', level: 1 },
      { name: 'shield', level: 5 }
    ]
  }
```

and i want to return all knights with skills of sword and shield. 
something like this (pseudo):

```
Knight.find({ skills.name: which contains ['sword', 'shield'] })
```

how do i do this kind of query?
thanks!

Comment: You want to test both `sword` and `shield` is in array?

Comment: the above pseudo code would return both knights, as it contains both skills with sword and shield

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to find inside the array with [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator

```
db.collection.find({
  skills: {
    $elemMatch: {
      name: { $in: ["sword", "shield"] }
    }
  }
})
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "name": "Knightley",
    "skills": [
      {
        "level": 2,
        "name": "sword"
      },
      {
        "level": 1,
        "name": "shield"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Cowardly",
    "skills": [
      {
        "level": 1,
        "name": "sword"
      },
      {
        "level": 5,
        "name": "shield"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Check it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/H4zOCETQHws)